# How to select my selected customer orders in sql between specific dates

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Hello I want to list my selected customer invoices between selected dates.

I have created a form

```
<form action="raporlar.php" method="POST">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <label for="">Customer Name</label>
    <select name="customerID" id="customerID" required="" class="form-control">
      <option value="">Select a customer</option>
      <?php 
      $musteriSor=$db->prepare('SELECT * FROM customer'); 
      $musteriSor->execute();
      while ($musteriCek=$musteriSor->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $musteriCek['ID']; ?>"><?php echo $musteriCek['adi']; ?></option>
      <?php } ?>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-7">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <label for="">First Date</label>
        <input type="date" name="firstDate" required="" class="form-control">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <label for="">Second Date</label>
        <input type="date" name="secondDate" required="" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <input type="submit" name="raporla" value="Raporla" class="btn">
  </div>
</form>
```

and this is my sql query

```
<?php 
$queryim = 'SELECT * FROM invoice WHERE customerID=:customerID and date=:date BETWEEN '.$_POST['firstDate'].' AND '.$_POST['secondDate'].'';
$faturaSor=$db->prepare($queryim); 
$faturaSor->execute(array('customerID'=>$_POST['customerID']));
while ($faturaCek=$faturaSor->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { 
    ... 
}
?>
```

and it gives this error -> **Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number:** number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in /test.local/raporlar.php on line 89

How can I list selected customer orders or invoices between selected 2 dates.

Answer (score 2):

you got 2 parameters in query `:customerID` and `:date` but in exeture() you are passing an array with just 1 element, you should modify your query code in the following way

```
$queryim = 'SELECT * FROM invoice WHERE customerID=:customerID and date BETWEEN :date1 AND :date2;
$faturaSor=$db->prepare($queryim); 
$faturaSor->execute(array('customerID'=>$_POST['customerID'],'date1'=>$_POST['firstDate'],'date2'=>$_POST['secondDate']));
```

You should also check the date format in $_POST, it can be different from database default (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS)